# Disable mousepointer and link in CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, href, mouse-cursor

On my website I have some pages that has mousepointers/URLS in the background, I can't find why only some pages have this active.

I tried:

```
a. {
   pointer-events: none; 
}
```

,to disable the mousepointer and the link, it works but for the whole page! I only want it on the background because if you click on the images you need to see the hover tekst (the link below shows you more clear what I mean).

http://jessicadenhartog.nl/experience/

I see in the HTML that a itemprop happens on these pages, how can I change that with CSS because I cannot reach the HTML in the Wordpress theme:

```
<a itemprop="url"href="http://jessicadenhartog.nl/work/"style="height: 43px;"</a>
```

Comment: why is there a period after the a? if you're adding CSS to a tag you do not need any punctuation

Answer (score 2):

You should add the following CSS:

```
a[itemprop="url"] {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: yes thanks, but also works only for the whole page, it's also diasbles every button that just needed to be clicked on this page, do you understand me?

Comment: Yes, I understand. I'll have a look once the site is online again.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with JavaScript. clicking on `a` will do nothing and hover effect will not be destroyed as well. try this

```
<a onclick="return false;" itemprop="url" href="http://jessicadenhartog.nl/work/" style="height: 43px;" <="" a="">
```